Kdb DbMaint from symbol to symbol List
I have an existing symbol column in HDB and want to cast that to a symbol list, can anyone advise what is the best way of doing that?
I know that adding a column is as follows:
.ds.hdb.addCol[`:.;`tab;`eventType;enlist`$()]

but how would we cast an existing one?

https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/blob/master/utils/dbmaint.md#fncol
fncol[`:.;`tab;`eventType;{enlist each x}]


For a even shorter function: enlist each instead of {enlist each x} should work too

The reason why you need to use each because you are converting each sym atom in the symbol list to a symbol list.

For completeness consider using append to an empty list also, in case you need to handle a mixture of lists and atoms: fncol[`:.;`tab;`eventType;(),/:]
